# Please help me about limit of <li> on this php sneppet

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this snippet to display chapter of story. But I dunno why, it is limited and only display 10 items. I can't solve this problem. Please you help me, man.

```html
global $post;   
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'story',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID
    );
    $story = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $story->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="story__main">
            <h2 class="story__title-chapter">Danh sách các chương</h2>
            <ul class="story__chapter">
            <?php
              while( $story->have_posts() ) :
                $story->the_post();?>
                <li>
                  <a href=<?php echo the_permalink();?>><?php echo get_the_title();?></a>
                  </li>
                  <?php endwhile;?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `posts_per_page` value.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'story',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
```

Important Note: This can result in a very huge query that can bring the site down. Do this only if you are sure your database can handle it. Not in public themes or plugins.

**Reference**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters